# Get list of all map services in a Web App in ArcGIS Portal

Tags: arcgis-portal

I'm in charge of moving our test Portal maps into production and looking for an easy way to get a list of all the layer sources in the web map.  In addition it would be great to be able to export a text file with the widgets, and settings for that web app.

Comment: Have you used ago-assistant. You have access to the json describing the nature of all the web maps, layer, etc. You can even edit the json to update. You look 1 by 1. Python API would probably get you everything you are looking for in a more automated way.

Comment: Hi Tim, I forgot about that.  I had used it years ago, but remembered it was not a supported tool or workflow.  I didn't realize people were still developing it!  I tried to connect to my internal portal and it gave me an error on the URL...  Any experience with that?

Comment: No experience with internal portal. Sorry.

Comment: I've used ago-assistant just fine with an on-premise portal. Works well. Portal was using IWA. AGO-Assistant has come a long way. Not sure how to provide support beyond telling you the URL should just be like http://www.myserver.com/portal/

Comment: I just read something about registering the app in portal to obtain an appId.  Did you do this to get your portal url to work?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using ESRI's [ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/). Once you have a `WebMap` object, you can find the layers from `webmap.layers`, and each layer object will have a `url` attribute.

You can leverage the Python API using [Esri powered notebooks](http://notebooks.esri.com/) if you're more comfortable working in the web browser and copying code in from [samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-web-maps-and-web-scenes/) than writing complete Python scripts.

Update: per your comment, to copy a webmap from one portal to another, there is a good workflow example on [this page](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/clone-portal-users-groups-and-content/). Some relevant code snippets:

```py
def copy_item(target, source_item):
    try:
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            item_properties = {}
            for property_name in ITEM_COPY_PROPERTIES:
                item_properties[property_name] = source_item[property_name]

            data_file = None

            if source_item.type in TEXT_BASED_ITEM_TYPES:
                # If its a text-based item, then read the text and add it to the request.
                text = source_item.get_data(False)
                item_properties['text'] = text

            elif source_item.type in FILE_BASED_ITEM_TYPES:
                # download data and add to the request as a file
                data_file = source_item.download(temp_dir)

            thumbnail_file = source_item.download_thumbnail(temp_dir)
            metadata_file = source_item.download_metadata(temp_dir)

            #find item's owner
            source_item_owner = source.users.search(source_item.owner)[0]

            #find item's folder
            item_folder_titles = [f['title'] for f in source_item_owner.folders 
                                  if f['id'] == source_item.ownerFolder]
            folder_name = None
            if len(item_folder_titles) > 0:
                folder_name = item_folder_titles[0]

            #if folder does not exist for target user, create it
            if folder_name:
                target_user = target.users.search(source_item.owner)[0]
                target_user_folders = [f['title'] for f in target_user.folders
                                       if f['title'] == folder_name]
                if len(target_user_folders) == 0:
                    #create the folder
                    target.content.create_folder(folder_name, source_item.owner)

            # Add the item to the target portal, assign owner and folder
            target_item = target.content.add(item_properties, data_file, thumbnail_file, 
                                             metadata_file, source_item.owner, folder_name)

            #Set sharing (privacy) information
            share_everyone = source_item.access == 'public'
            share_org = source_item.access in ['org', 'public']
            share_groups = []
            if source_item.access == 'shared':
                share_groups = source_item.groups

            target_item.share(share_everyone, share_org, share_groups)

            return target_item

    except Exception as copy_ex:
        print("\tError copying " + source_item.title)
        print("\t" + str(copy_ex))
        return None
```

You would probably need to adjust this for your specific requirements, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks!  This is great for the layer list.  Looking around the api for something that can replicate the widget settings within a web app, or ability to copy a web app from test to prod.  Don't see anything.  Any advice there?